# Merge List of Dictionaries into a Single List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that all follow the same format. I want to alter the list of dictionaries to return just the values from all the objects like so.

```
[{"name": "Dwight"}, {"name": "Michael"}, {"name": "Jim"}] -> ["Dwight", "Michael", "Jim"]
```

I realize I can iterate through the list and grab the values from each object, but I was wondering if there's any easier/built in python way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: "iterate through the list and grab the values from each object" is the actual Python way, even if you use a fancy construct to hide the iteration.

Comment: `[d['name'] for d in lst]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hardly beat an explicit list comprehension:

```
[v for d in my_list for v in d.values()]
```

or maybe you meant

```
[d['name'] for d in my_list if 'name' in d]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by iterating through a dictionary and building a list, then you probably meant that you already know to do this:

```
dictionaries_in_list = [{"name": "Dwight"}, {"name": "Michael"}, {"name": "Jim"}]
list = []

for dictionary in dictionaries_in_list:
    list.append(dictionary['name'])

print(list)
```

This is a legitimate pythonic way to express code.  Are you asking for a one-liner instead of a two-liner?  @It_is_Chris comment is a valid one-line solution.

```
dictionaries_in_list = [{"name": "Dwight"}, {"name": "Michael"}, {"name": "Jim"}]

it_is_christ_solution = [d['name'] for d in dictionaries_in_list]

print(it_is_christ_solution)
```

Both of @YvesgereY's are valid one-liners, too.